# User does not have permission to perform action - trying to log in to an asp.net login page

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, login-control

I've Developed an asp.net website which require users to login using the default asp.net login control and local SQl. 
unfortunately we had to reload the PC with a fresh copy of Win7 Now, I got the IIS7 back up and user can navigate to the login.aspx page, but trying to log in I  get the following error. "User does not have permission to perform action"  -now I have recreated all the user under the asp.net Configuration under Visual Studio 2012 and still nothing. Any advice where to start solving it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create user on your SQL ? create a new login.And change your connectionstring.

forexample create a user in sql 
and add this connection string to your web config inside

```
 <connectionStrings> <add name="xxxConnectionstr" connectionString="Data Source=.\;Initial Catalog=yourdatabasename"; Uid="yoursqluser"; Pwd="yourpassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/></connectionStrings>
```

I think your connection string contains "Integrated Security=True" and this means u are logging in with windows user.And when you change windows 7,user changed